# How to work with FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I work with FreeMarker. What I now need is something like template inheritance in smarty (php world).

I have a base.ftl, where all the javascript and css stuff will be loaded:

(*Simplified:*)

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <title>MyApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${content}
    </body>
</html>
```

And lets say I have a template for listing users (users.ftl):

```
<ul>
   <li>User1</li>
   <li>User2</li>
</ul>
```

I did some research and found that I could use `<#include "...">` but I am sure there is another elegant way.

And one further question: What if I want to add in the ${content} the output of users.ftl AND products.ftl:

```
<ul>
   <li>Product1</li>
   <li>Product2</li>
</ul>
```

How would the Controller looks like?
Currently mine looks like:

```
package org.domain.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller("indexController")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String indexAction(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("content", "How to get the output of users.ftl and products.ftl??");
        return "base";
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at namespaces and import. http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_namespace.html

Comment: I would use `#import`+`#macro` instead of `#include`, but that's not very different in its approach. So why exactly do you want it to be a variable instead? Also, you could specify the name of the actual content template in the data-model, rather than its output.

Comment: Or, maybe the action should use directly what you call `content.ftl` here, and `content.ftl` should pull the `base.ftl` around itself like `<@base.page>...</@base.page>` or something.

Comment: Actually I simply want to have a base template where I define all my script and style tags that ALL of my views have common. And in my controller I want to be able to create as many views as I want and show them. Currently I am only able to call ONLY ONE template in my controller by returning the name of the ftl file.

Comment: Consider adding apache tiles for Your project, it integrates well with ftl and spring giving template inheritance out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sample pom
     <!-- Spring boot capacity added -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Sample class for templete configuration:

```
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;
               
        import freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader;
        import freemarker.template.Configuration;
        import freemarker.template.TemplateExceptionHandler;
        
        public class TemplateConfig {
        
            private static Configuration configuration;
        
            private TemplateConfig() {
                buildCodegenConfig();
            }
            
            public static Configuration get() {
                new TemplateConfig();
                return configuration;
            }
        
            private static void buildCodegenConfig() {
        
                configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29);
                configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        
                // Sets how errors will appear.
                configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        
                // Don't log exceptions inside FreeMarker that it will thrown at you anyway:
                configuration.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
        
                // Wrap unchecked exceptions thrown during template processing into
                // TemplateException-s:
                configuration.setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true);
        
                // Do not fall back to higher scopes when reading a null loop variable:
                configuration.setFallbackOnNullLoopVariable(false);
                
                try {
                    FileTemplateLoader templateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("src/main/resources/templates"));
                    configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        
            }
        }
    
    //Sample template fetcher
    
    import freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader;
    import freemarker.template.Configuration;
    import freemarker.template.Template;
    
    
    public class TemplateFetcher {
        
        private static Configuration configuration = TemplateConfig.get();
        
        public static Template getTemplate(String tempplateName) {
            try {
                FileTemplateLoader templateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("src/main/resources/templates"));
                configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
                return configuration.getTemplate(tempplateName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    }


//sample pojos

public class PageBean {
     private List<QuestionBean> questionsList;
}

public class QuestionBean {
    
    private String questionName;
    private String id;
    private String labelText;
    private String eventAttributeKey;
    private String refDataSetName;
    private String required;
    private String optionsAvailable;
    private String questionType;
    private String orderedBy;
}
    
    //sample code to read freemarker template (.ftlh) and write the file
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import TemplateFetcher;
    
    import freemarker.template.Template;
    
    public class CodeWriter {
    
        public static void writeSourceCodeFile(Map<Object, Object> dataMap) {
//This datamap holds an object "pageBean" which has list of another object "question" which I'm not showing here.           

Writer fileWriter = null;
    
            String packageNameFolder = "C:\\Users\\abc\\destinationFolder";
    
            String fileName = "xyz.html";
    
            try {
                new File(packageNameFolder).mkdirs();
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(packageNameFolder + File.separator + fileName));
                Template template = TemplateFetcher.getTemplate("htmlFile.ftlh");
                template.process(dataMap, fileWriter);
                fileWriter.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
    
                try {
                    if (null != fileWriter) {
                        fileWriter.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    
        }
    }


//sample htmlFile.ftlh

<#list pageBean.questionsList as eachQuestion> 
    ${eachQuestion.questionName}("${eachQuestion.id}", "${eachQuestion.labelText}", <#if eachQuestion.eventAttributeKey?has_content>"${eachQuestion.eventAttributeKey}" <#else>EMPTY</#if>, <#if eachQuestion.refDataSetName?has_content>"${eachQuestion.refDataSetName}" <#else>EMPTY</#if>, ${eachQuestion.required}, ${eachQuestion.optionsAvailable}, ${eachQuestion.questionType}, ${eachQuestion.orderedBy})<#sep>,
</#list>;
```